# Cannot import RecordFactory from immutable.js

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js, react-typescript

I'm not sure why but I'm getting an error when I'm trying to import 'RecordFactory' from immutable.js:

[image]

The error is: Module '"immutable"' has no exported member 'RecordFactory'.ts(2305)

Env: react-typescript-immutable v ^4.0.0-rc.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is wrong there, in TypeScript it's `Record.Factory<T>` (note the dot in the middle).
There is an open [issue](https://github.com/immutable-js-oss/immutable-js/issues/122) for it on GitHub

Comment: How can I change my code to work with Record.Factory<T> I'm having a hard time finding a solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-dawn-yw4ok?file=/src/reducer.ts
Thanks

Comment: @Shira Just replace RecordFactory with Record.Factory? I am not sure what you are referring to? That sandbox has a few TS errors because it seems to be incomplete

Comment: Please re-check the code I fixed it, I change RecordFactory with Record.Factory but it throwing an error now : https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-dawn-yw4ok?file=/src/reducer.ts

Comment: I think I figure this out: https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-dawn-yw4ok?file=/src/reducer.ts